Entire Row in default Tooltip issue in Power BI Table visual
I have created couple of grids / table visuals in Power BI. Sometimes Default Tooltip comes correctly for a Cell.  But sometimes it comes for entire row. Correct and issue is below, also For some visuals Tooltip is Truncating in Power BI Table visual. IDK how to control that...How to control tool tip behavior in Power BI Table visual.
CORRECT TOOLTIP

Entire Row as tooltip (ISSUE)

Truncated tooltip

